# Node.js web app vs Java Web App (Spring MVC on Tomcat 6)

Tags: java, node.js

I am trying to rewrite a Java Web App written on Spring MVC 3 which uses a tomcat server.

The web app serves to handle rest requests from a mobile phone app. The Java web app also has a front end rendering pages in JSP.

Now I have begun on node using the express-framework. Now can I expect a node-app to perform better than a Java web-app ? How do I go about stress testing the two and arrive at a conclusion ?

Following are the typical requests my web-app must handle

1. Fetch paginated records from the database
2. Obtain the great circular distance between two geo points, passed as parameters to the rest service

Answer (score 0):

Try using [ab](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html) for stress loading how fast are page are loading. Do it from different machine if you can.

Also you have [nodeload](https://github.com/benschmaus/nodeload) project, which is fine.